# How to show data only to followers or following users in Firebase Database in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am working on app similar to LinkedIn and here I have some users already added to Firebase Database. Also every user can post or upload some content as well. Now am looking for a technique or code snippet that allows me to list the posts only to those who follow others. ***"For example: if am following you I'll be able to see your uploaded content in feeds or home screen".*** For listing out the posts am using **Firebase Recycler Adapter and RecyclerView**.

Below is my code for listing the posts:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);

    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    final String userID = user.getUid();

    Query query = myRef;

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<PostInfo> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PostInfo>()
            .setQuery(query, PostInfo.class)
            .build();

    FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostInfo, PostViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull PostInfo model) {

                holder.setPostUser(model.getPostUser());

                holder.setPostImage(model.getPostImage(), getActivity());

                holder.setPostDesc(model.getPostDesc());

                holder.setPostLikes(model.getPostLikes());

                holder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        holder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_like_22);

                        holder.mLike.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1F7FB1"));

                    }
                });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.post_card, parent, false);

            return new PostViewHolder(view);

        }
    };

    mPostList.setAdapter(FBRA);

    FBRA.startListening();

}
```

Here are the Database screenshots:

**Below is a user who has accepted my request which means I follow him now:**

[image]

**These are user posts:**

[image]

I also thought of using **orderByChild().equals("theFollower")**, could not figured it out.
**How can achieve it? How only limited users i.e, only followers can see my posts?**

Thanks a lot!